# Java class HiveDriver not found when conecting to database Hive with Anaconda and Python 3.8 64bits

Tags: python, jdbc, hive, anaconda, jupyter

For the past few days I have encountered an issue that I cannot explain.
I am on Windows 10, Anaconda 64bits, Jupyter 64bits, Python 64bits, etc...
I am a beginner and I need help. Thank you very much for the help which is greatly appreciated.
I develop under anaconda jupyter notebook, I have a python script that connects to a Hive database using jdbc.
I added a jar file which contains a java class org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.
When I run the script I got the following error:

TypeError: Class org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver is not found

### Here is my python code

```
import jaydebeapi

driver = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"
url = "jdbc:hive2://ip-172-31-3-208.eu-west-1.compute.internal:11000/default;principal=indexima/ip-172-31-3-208.eu-west-1.compute.internal@INDEXIMA.COM;"
hivejar = "C:/user/xxx/Documents/Python/hive-jdbc-3.1.2.jar"


#create connection and cursor
connection = jaydebeapi.connect(driver, [ url, '', ''], hivejar)
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

---

And the ouput is:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-15-3a47c2c3c553> in <module>
         11 
         12 # create connection and cursor
    ---> 13 connection = jaydebeapi.connect(driver, [ url, '', ''], hivejar)
         14 cursor = connection.cursor()
         15 

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jaydebeapi\__init__.py in connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
        410     else:
        411         libs = []
    --> 412     jconn = _jdbc_connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
        413     return Connection(jconn, _converters)
        414 

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jaydebeapi\__init__.py in _jdbc_connect_jpype(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
        219             return jpype.JArray(jpype.JByte, 1)(data)
        220     # register driver for DriverManager
    --> 221     jpype.JClass(jclassname)
        222     if isinstance(driver_args, dict):
        223         Properties = jpype.java.util.Properties

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jpype\_jclass.py in __new__(cls, jc, loader, initialize)
         97 
         98         # Pass to class factory to create the type
    ---> 99         return _jpype._getClass(jc)
        100 
        101 

    **TypeError: Class org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver is not found**
```

The jar file contains of course the java class HiveDriver.
I changed the name of the jar and replaced with any name, and I got the same diagnosis.
It is as if Jupyter is going to look elsewhere.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a small mis-configuration in the parameters you are using here:

```py
connection = jaydebeapi.connect(driver, [ url, '', ''], hivejar)
```

The URL should not be placed in the `[ ]` array - only the user ID and password strings.

Use this instead:

```py
connection = jaydebeapi.connect(driver, url, ['', ''], hivejar)
```

More examples are [here](https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/#id2) in the offical documentation.